# $a \in \mathbb{N}$ and $p \in \mathbb{P}$ with $gcd(a, p-1)=1$, then for every integer $b$, then $x^a \equiv b$ mod $p$ has a solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'd like to show the following: Let $a \in \mathbb{N}$ and $p \in \mathbb{P}$ with $gcd(a, p-1)=1$, then for every integer $b$, the congruence relation $x^a \equiv b$ mod $p$ has a solution.

If $p \mid b$, then this trivially holds. For the other case, I've started with showing that there exists a $c$ such that $a*c \equiv 1$ (mod $p-1$) and I think that $x = b^c$ should satisfy the relation, but I've not yet been able to show this. Can someone help me?

Thanks!